# How can i export all table viewer contents to xml in javafx?

Tags: java, xml, javafx

I want to export my table viewer contents xml.I have 5 tables and i want all tables to be exported to a xml file on clicking export.I have a model which is a  observablearraylist which contains another observablearraylist which contains a map.Is there any way to export my contents to xml.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a javaFx problem per se. 
You will need to use something like [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html)